# Moving from <hostname>:1234 to <hostname>/app

Tags: port, url

I'm bringing up my first production-level(-ish) server and have installed and configured a couple of python web applications, which I have to access like so:

```
<hostname>:8000
<hostname>:8001
```

The port is not so important, I can choose it of course. My question is if I should use Apache, DNSs, Apache+DNSs (and to what degree), or something completely different to move from that url scheme to a friendlier one:

```
<hostname>/app1
<hostname>/app2
```

Comment: For HTTP port must be `80` if you don't want it included in the URL, and 443 for HTTPS.

Comment: Apache reverse-proxy or redirect directives can do what he's asking for though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to configure either a reverse-proxy or a redirect directive in Apache; you don't specify port numbers with DNS.

Comment: This looks like a sensible guide I'll check: http://blog.lundscape.com/2009/05/configure-a-reverse-proxy-with-apache/

Answer (score 3):

Easy way : Keep the existing configuration same. Try rewriting  the URL using mod_rewrite

Hard way: If you have access to DNS, you could have a seperate sub domains for different applications e.g. app-a.example.com , app-b.example.com

Comment: That works too.